# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when calling a reference project class method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

[image: Here is the project structure][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xvun.png)[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10iyu.png)I have made a spring restful dynamic web project and add as a reference in the second spring restful dynamic web project but having a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when calling the reference project method.I have include the reference project in the class path and also in the deployment assembly. 
Here is the code.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/get")
public class GetController {

@GetMapping("/admin")
public ArrayList<Admin> get(){
    ArrayList<Admin> admins = new ArrayList<Admin>();
    AdminDao adminDao = new AdminDao(); // this is reference project object
    ArrayList<com.model.Admin> adminModel = new ArrayList<com.model.Admin(); // this is reference project Admin object
    adminModel = adminDao.getAllAdmin();
    for(int i=0; i<adminModel.size(); i++){
        admins.get(i).setAddress(adminModel.get(i).getAddress());
        admins.get(i).setAge(adminModel.get(i).getAge());
        admins.get(i).setEmail(adminModel.get(i).getEmail());
        admins.get(i).setId(adminModel.get(i).getId());
        admins.get(i).setName(adminModel.get(i).getName());
        admins.get(i).setPassword(adminModel.get(i).getPassword());
    }
    return admins;
}
```

}

Here is the stack trace

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [/RestData] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/dao/AdminDao] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.dao.AdminDao
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
at com.controller.GetController.get(GetController.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Tell me what the mistake i have done.
Thanks.

Comment: Please add project structure. I can't understand what means "spring restful dynamic web project and add as a reference in the second spring restful dynamic web project".  How you testing this on IDE r on server?

Comment: @SauliusNext I added the structure

Comment: Add package explorer view. If you mixing project I suggest common parts move to separate java project.

Comment: @SauliusNext i added the package explorer

Comment: Please read this and i hope that this will guide you to the right way https://spring.io/blog/2007/06/11/using-a-shared-parent-application-context-in-a-multi-war-spring-application/